# PHP INCLUDE - injection possible?

Tags: php, include, code-injection

Recently my server got hacked and files were uploaded. Right now I'm trying to locate the weak spots, which brought me to php injection. 
I use the following code to include files:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {

$page = $_GET['page'];

include("./php/$page.php");
}
```

I've tried something like:

```
http://badsite.com/badcode.php
example.php");include(...BADCODE HERE...);//
```

"allow_url_fopen=0" is disabled in the server configuration. I think a white list and/or php functions (htmlentities, strip...) to filter special charecters and code by default would make it bulletproof. But still I'm wondering if it is possible to inject bad code anyway as the value of $page is treated as a string?

Is there anything a "user" could enter, that will not end up in php warning "...failed to open stream: No such file or directory..."?

Comment: Not saying it's your problem, but I've seen that people using plain FTP will often get hacked. If you were using plain FTP, simply using encrypted FTP, SFTP, etc would be a great start to keeping your sites safe. I learned this lesson the hard way, when I was on the same network with a computer that had malware. It was actually my mom's computer. It was sniffing network traffic and sending my FTP credentials to China.

Comment: That's not how PHP works; it isn't rewriting the code with the values it's provided, unless you're using something like `eval()`. It just interprets the value and puts it into a variable. Your only real risk lies with traversal attacks that might try putting `../` into the path to try and include a file that shouldn't be included.

Comment: `inculde`  can you fix that typo please? unless it isn't one?

Comment: Thx for your answers. I use encrypted FTP, but I was thinking about similar ways, hackers might have gained control... I know about eval() function, preg_replace() and others, this was really only about include, but jh1711 gave me a good hint about null byte injection. @Funk Forty Niner: Typo fixed- thx! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to local file inclusion (LFI). A potential attacker can traverse your file system and include something like:

```
page=../../uploads/images/1.jpg
```

The example shows one of the potential exploits for LFI. If you allow image uploads, somebody can upload an image that includes PHP code, and that code will be executed. Other exploits hide PHP code in session files or log files; and include the file through the vulnerability.

In itself the problem is not a big issue, but it can become one when combined with something else. Therefore I would whitelist what pages I allow for $_GET['page'].

Comment: OP is appending `.php` to the variable, which will mitigate things somewhat.

Comment: You're right. I totally missed that. The attack scenarios should still be real, but I need to check what PHP versions still allow null byte poisoning to bypass the hardcoded extension. I'll update the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Damn! I got a complete new account from my provider, so I can't tell which PHP version was running. From what I found out "Null byte injection has been fixed in PHP 5.3.4"... Probably I had an older version running. THX so far for the hint!!!

Comment: Damn me too. I forgot that I wanted to get back to this question. Mea culpa. It seems null bytes have been fixed for ages; that should be a thing of the not to recent past. But as far as I can tell path truncation (add a bunch of meaningless `././` (around 4kB), and  the extension will be cut of) is still an issue. At least that's what a few quick tests shoe. It may not show in your setup, if your config limits $_GET strings to a length shorter than that.

Comment: Took me a while.... But many thanks for your last reply as well. I got into this a little deeper, hoping I could fix the issues on my site :)